# MVC 5 CSS it not working properly in IE9 & 10

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

Even i have set the following in Layout.cshtml while it's working fine in mozila & Chrome but it's not working fine in IE 10 & IE9

what i did so far

1- added to layout

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

2- added site to compatibility setting of IE

but still same problem it's not showing menus properly in IE10 & 9

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using "for-of". But its not supported for these internet explorer versions.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of